# Unable to move, quit software. Minimize maximize and quit is missing

Tags: gui, selinux

I restarted my pc after the update. Now I am unable to move any applications. even quit. The application just stuck with left up corner. Even not showing which application is running in the taskbar. . Whenever I took the cursor in the taskbar, it's showing cross.
Maybe it's a duplicate question. But no solution working well or an outdated solution. so I need help.
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfBy4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using the below command. It fixed all my GUI issues.

```
xfwm4
```

Open a terminal by ctrl + alt + t and type this command and press enter to fix it.